# LIKE statement SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

**Dont work brackets in LIKE statement**

I use MySQL WorkBench, I dont understand why `SELECT * from user where name like'B[io]'` dont work.

My DataBase:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because MySQL does not support character classes in `like` expressions.  Neither does the SQL standard.

Use regular expressions:

```
where name regexp '^B[io]'
```

Incidentally, the `like` *does* work.  You just have no data that starts with the five characters `'B'`, `'['`, `'i'`, `'o'`, and '`]'` in that order.